# Show only images with specific keyword

Tags: assets

I am trying to display images tagged with a specific Keyword, however I also appear to be getting images that have my keywords in the images filename. Is this correct behaviour or am I just not getting my tags right? Code below..

```
{exp:assets:folders recursive="yes"}
    <h3>{folder_name}</h3>
    <ul>
        {exp:assets:files folder_id="{folder_id}" keywords="London"}
            <li><a href="{url:huge}" target="_blank">{if title != ""}{title}{if:else}{filename}{/if}</a></li>
        {/exp:assets:files}
    </ul>
{/exp:assets:folders}
```

Comment: I guess you could always use it in combination with the query module to further limit the filtering if you really needed to.

Answer (score 1):

it's the expected behaviour for Assets.